# MacOS Pinyin input method currency symbol

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

From what I gathered, it seems that the Pinyin simplified input method hardcoded that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> inputs a Yuan symbol ¥, and I don't see a way to change it to other currency symbols. I would like it to just input $ instead, since it is used as important operators in programming etc. Changing the system language, region and currency designation doesn't work. Is there a known way to do this, or do I have to install a third-party input method?

Comment: If you do choose to go the 3rd party route, I'd highly recommend [Karabiner Elements.](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use text substitution to simply have the OS replace the "¥" with "$" any time you type it.

I just tested it, and single character replacements work fine.

Comment: This works very well, but definitely looks a bit hacky. I'll wait a bit to see if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Caps Lock Shift 4 should give you $